# Understanding segfault behavior in printf

Tags: c

Let's take the following code which will segfault (note, I'm intentionally using `%s` instead of `%c` here for this question):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char c = 'x';
    printf("%s", c);
    return 0;
}
```

> Segmentation fault: 11

Why does the segfault occur? Here is my current understanding of it.

The `printf` receives a `%s` input and infers that the variable at that position is a pointer to a string. It then tries to read the characters at the memory address given by the string and print them out until hitting `\0`. However, when it gets to `c`, it tries to access the memory address of the value of `c` (character `x` or `0x78`) in which case it obviously cannot access memory address `0x78`. Is that a correct understanding? Additionally, what happens when a string is entered in directly?

```
printf("%s", "OK");
```

Does `OK` get pulled out when compiling and turned into a memory address with the value `OK` in rodata, or how does that work?

Comment: `c` is a `char`, so you need `%c`. For `%s`, you need: `char *c = "x";`

Comment: If you compiled with warnings enabled (`-Wall`), this would have been flagged by the compiler

Comment: It's not address `0x78`, it's probably something like `0x78000...` depending on your endianness.

Comment: @CraigEstey right I'm intentionally creating a segfault here. I just wanted to see how it occurs in the particular case.

Comment: As written, `c` is the first argument. It is sign extended to `int` [_usually_ 32 bits]. `%s` expects a `char *` _pointer_. So, the pointer value will be 0x00000078 (the ASCII value for `'x'`). So, `printf` will dereference that location, which will invoke UB (undefined behavior). It will segfault on _some_ systems that map page 0 (0x00000000-0x00000FFF) to a page that disallows any access, so you will get `SIGSEGV`. This is done [as a debugging aid] to trap such things.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382849/is-stack-overflow-too-pedantic-about-undefined-behaviors#comment687704_382849

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that c only occupies one byte, and printf tries to read a whole pointer at c's address (somewhere on the stack). From there on, it's undefined behavior etc, but anyway, whatever it reads (maybe something like: `0x78` `0x0` `0x0` `0x0`) , it tries to dereference as an address, at which point, you get the segfault.

Re second question, yes that sounds about right.

Answer (score 3):

Your explanation of the segfault is pretty much right.  Interpreting the char as a pointer (memory address) is the problem and will do something unexpected, which is most likely going to be a segfault but doesn't have to be.

As for how `printf("%s", "OK");` works, the string literal `"OK"` as the second parameter to `printf` is treated as a pointer to the read-only string `OK` that the compiler creates, so that's why it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing here is `printf` uses *varargs* which aren't your typical arguments. They don't get automatically converted because they're usually heaped together by the compiler on the call stack and "decoded" by the function you call based on that function's expectations.

Those expectations are defined by the function's internals, not C's typical argument handler. In the case of `printf` it uses the template string as a guide as to what to look for, working through the stack by casting each component as it identifies it.

In your case you have a single `char`. It's expecting a pointer, so that plus the remaining 3-7 bytes are just presumed to be that pointer, and that pointer is obviously invalid.

The stack might be all `00` bytes, but it could be random junk as well like `DEADBEEF`, it depends on what your compiler does in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the segfault occur?
> ...  However, when it gets to c, it tries to access the memory address of the value of c (character x or 0x78) in which case it obviously cannot access memory address 0x78. Is that a correct understanding?

No.  That behavior is **not** specified by C.

`char c; printf("%s", c);` --> The expected pointer for `"%s"` is not certainly derived from `c` in whole or in part. The argument passing mechanisms for `char` and `char *` may be entirely different.   It is simple *undefined behaver* (UB).

"Is that a correct understanding?" is more like "Is that a possible understanding among many?" (which is true as it is UB)

---

> Does OK get pulled out when compiling and turned into a memory address with the value OK in rodata, or how does that work?

That, again, is one possibility.  C is allowed to analyze  its library functions and the following may emit very efficient code without any use of rodata.

```
// printf("%s", "OK");
// May compile to pseudo assembly
write('O');
write('K');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a good understanding of strings, but you've made a few mistakes that create some rather unexpected behavior.

A string is a pointer to character (`char *`). By initializing the variable `c` with only the `char` specifier, you are telling the compiler that `c` is a character and not a string as you were aiming for. To fix this, we simply need to add an asterisk, which denotes a pointer

In C, single quotes (`'`) denote characters and double quotes (`''`) character arrays, or strings. Therefore, the single quotes around your string should be replaced by double quotes so that your program knows you are assigning `c` a string and not a single character.

From these two fixes, we can correct the code:

> ```
> int main(void) {
>     char *c = "x";
>     printf("%s", c);
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

The reason why the program segmentation faults is because it is trying to access a segment of memory that it does not have access to. You see, `printf()` and many other functions that work with strings take advantage of the null character (`0` or `\0`). By using the format specifier `%s`, `printf()` expects a string, and thus will not stop reading the memory next to your variable until a null character is found. As you passed only a character, your program won't have access to this memory. When your program tries to do access it, your program stops as a security measure.